# Generate test report for positive and negative test scenarios using flutter integration_test

Tags: testing, error-handling, automated-tests, integration-testing, flutter-test

I am new to Flutter and Integration test framework. While run the automation test, I wish to generate the test report which includes positive and negative test scenarios(test results) also I want to communicate this test report to dev team when the test fails. Any tools can fulfill this requirement? Please advice!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.